# How to send a mandatory data from an action to an other action in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. I have an account controller and from it I want to send a value to an other action of an other controller called Gate. To do this I used TempData like as follows:

```
 public IActionResult SendDataToGate(string username)
 {
      TempData["username"] = username;
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Gate");
 }
```

And here is the Gate controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     string usenamedata = TempData["username"] as string;
     TempData.Keep("username");
     var gates = _context.Gate;
     return View(await gates.ToListAsync());
}

// GET: Gates/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Gate gate)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          _context.Set<Gate>().Add(new Gate
          {
                Name = gate.Name,
                // username = ??
                Type = gate.Type,
          });

          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
          return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
}
```

Now my problem is, I want to know how I can save the value of `tempData[username]` in username variable inside the [post]create method, after saving data in Create method. I appreciate of any help.

Comment: Temp data is removed when you consume it, so if you want to pass the temp data on from the GET to the POST, you will need to set it again. Alternatively, you could also include the data in the form post (e.g. using `<input type="hidden">`) so that it will survive multiple requests as well.

Comment: does the class object for ValidateAntiForgeryToken contain a username?  You are using entity and you are adding data to the Entity classes _context.  So you just need to set the username in the Entity classes.

Comment: the correct approach in this case is use a `hidden input`. Messing around with TempData (underlaid by some cookie or session state) is not necessary. The only thing you may have to think about is the amount of data returned to and received back from the client (all contained in the hidden inputs). If it's fairly large, then your design may be wrong (it does not make sense to pass back & forth such a large data). Usually such hidden data are for ids, names ... (some kinds of key or linking info - that should be small)

Comment: I want  just keep the user's username in tempData. I want whenever user save or edit a data, his username saves in the related table.

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain more clearly? I didn't understand How can I save the user's username which has a small amount of data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Session.
Startup.cs(I set `IdleTimeout` to one day):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                ............
                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

                services.AddSession(options =>
                {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                });
            }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .........

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //add UseSession here
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                .........
            });
        }
```

SendDataToGate:

```
public IActionResult SendDataToGate(string username)
 {
      HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", username);
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Gate");
 }
```

Gate controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     string usenamedata = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
     var gates = _context.Gate;
     return View(await gates.ToListAsync());
}
```